# Multiple Application Contexts having own container in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, junit

I have just started learning spring boot and started creating a testing framework with the help of it. With the help of singleton scope I am able to run my unit test cases sequentially but when I am trying to run my unit test cases in parallel then it is using single bean( because of single container ) for all the threads and because of that only the first test cases is able to get executed properly and all others are failing. I believe that if multiple application contexts are there and each having its own container then may be that could resolve my issue. If possible then please help me with the code snippet :)

Comment: The application context IS the container. Also why should it fail? Looks like you are doing things you shouldn't be doing in the first place in your service, like keeping state.

Comment: Actually in the framework there are some classes that are dependent on each other. hence in order to solve the dependencies, I need to keep the state. Any suggestion from you is welcome sir :)

Comment: I would strongly suggest to find another solution, as keeping state in singletons is basically trouble waiting to happen.